# Trigger on a page number. Or: fixing special content for a certain page

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

I found [this little joke](http://www.spotlighteffect.nl/media/internet/pagina-niet-gevonden-the-best-404/):

[image]

How would I do this in LaTeX? Is there some kind of tool I can use to trigger on a page number, like this:

```
 \trigger{404}{\Huge{The page cannot be found}\clearpage}
```

Or is there a different way to get this behaviour?

<sub>I don't have an MWE. It would be a simple document with a standard document class and some text.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) to perform page-related checking before shipout and condition accordingly. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{afterpage,atbegshi,lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginShipout{%
    \ifnum\value{page}=403
      \vspace*{\fill}
      {\raggedleft\Large
       The page \\ cannot be found\par}
      \vfill
      \clearpage
    \fi%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{400}% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-35]

\end{document}
```